# Отправка значений формы на почту без использования php

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, json

Нужно отправлять введенын пользователем данные на почту. Есть ли какие нибудь сервисы или плагины которые работают чисто на js(использую гитхаб как хостинг)

Comment: https://formspree.io/ <br>
Думаю, вы ищете что-то похожее

Answer (score 0):

Нет, я бы ответил, что такого нет.

Дело в том, что загрузке скрипта с какого то сервера JS, исполняемый в браузере, может общаться по сети только с этим сервером. Это называется CORS policy. Прочитать про это можно [здесь](https://webdevblog.ru/chto-takoe-cors/)

И как написано в этой статье, формирование заголовков, отвечающих за то, что Ваш скрипт может общаться с другими сайтами, делается на стороне сервера. Если это Ваш сервер - Вы можете его настроить как угодно. А если это гитхаб - то он точно настроен в соответсвии со стандартной CORS.

Кстати, есть очень интересная техника, котрая позволяет частично обойти это ограничение. И, например, просканировать из JS порты локальной сети. Это делается путем попытки загрузки изображения: сформироать ссылку можно локально, и указать в ней любой серер и порт. Потом если порт открыт - то ошибка при загрузке изображения другая, чем если порт закрыт.

Поэтому, если Вам нужно отправлять письма - нужно обзавестись страницей на сервере, которая делает это со стороны сервера.

Возможно, есть готовый сервис, который позволяет загрузить страницу и отправлять письма. Например, google forms.

Если у кого то есть опровержение моего мнения - я буду только рад его услышать.